# Replace control-m character in HDFS

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

So..., there is a bunch of data coming on to the edge node from various sources. Some of the files have control-M characters coming from comments section of a particular database.

Since the file lands on the edge node as a flat file and not sqoop, when the file is uploaded to hive, the control-m characters are treated as new records and the validation fails (hive table gets more rows than source)

The solution is straight forward, to remove the control-m using sed, perl what have you.

After the while, the edge node was too stressed and I was evaluating if data cleansing can be done on HDFS so the load is distributed (using map reduce) like so:

```
hadoop jar  /path/to/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2.jar  \
-input data/file_with_control-m.txt \
-mapper /bin/cat  \
-reducer "/bin/sh myreducer.sh"  \
-file "/home/shell/myreducer.sh"   \
-output data/output
```

myreducer.sh

```
perl -p -i -e "s/\r//g"

# or

sed 's/^M//g'
```

This works, but the problem is, the inherit property of map reduce being shuffle/sort the data is not ordered. Not just the "record", like 5th and 8th row are interchanged, even the fields with in each record are in random places. Map reduce doesn't guarantee ordering

Pig doesn't work either, the control-m character is treated like end of line and the data is loaded exactly like hive (more rows than given)

Other things considered are:

- To see if the Source system can cleanse the file
- Source system specifies a different record separator (I use that
  record     separator while creating hive table [lines terminated by
  'source system record seperator'])

While that's being done and knowing ordering and Map-Reduce doesn't go together, just putting it out there to see if there is a way around.

Comment: facing same issue in hive...the control-m character is treated like end of line and the data is loaded exactly like hive.... any solution found?

Comment: Na nothing, doing it at the edge node still